# How to injecting user-defined fields in binary package control files

Tags: package-management, dpkg, deb, packaging

It's possible to add user-defined fields in the debian/control file using the `XBS-` method, [as defined in the Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#user-defined-fields).

Something like this before calling dpkg-buildpackage will work to inject a new field into both the Source and Binary packages. But some packages don't contain debian/control as they generate it (kernel etc) so this is not always reliable.

```
sed -i "0,/^\s*$/s//XBS-Git-Branch: ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}\n/" debian/control
dpkg-buildpackage
```

It's possible to inject the user-defined field into the generated source package using [options passed to dpkg-source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/dpkg-buildpackage.1.html):

```
dpkg-buildpackage --source-option=-DGit-Branch=${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
```

However, that will only inject the field into the generated source package, not the generated binary packages. Is there a method to reliably inject fields into the binary packages?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, How about using [`substvars`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#variable-substitutions-debian-substvars) , put a complete line as variable  ex: `${myline}` then replace through `substvars` file.